# Angular not work in jQuery Ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I use ajax to dynamically load part of page in a Sails project views/homepage.ejs. 
The controller is "food", "show" is one action of "food", so I have a file /views/food/show.ejs. So by using Ajax load food/show, will load show.ejs.

```
$('#outerDiv').load("food/show",function(responseTxt,status,xhr){
  if(status!=="error"){
     alert("BOOT...");
     //bootstrap angular
     angular.bootstrap($("#outerDiv"));
  }
});
```

The content of show.ejs is like this:

```
<script>
  alert("LOAD..");
  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller("myCtrl",function (){
    this.numInStock= 10;
  })
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>The number in stock is: {{numInStock}}</p>
</div>
```

But the angular in that loaded page still cannot work, even I try to manually bootstrap angular for the new loaded page.

Alert(LOAD...) comes first, then Alert(BOOT...) comes next, while I found the new page was already rendered like "The number in stock is: {{numInStock}}". Obviously, it's wrong, I want it to be "The number in stock is: 10".

Chrome console gives an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22subPage%22%26gt%3B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `ng-app` from your HTML. Your Angular page is initialized on page load because you've added it to the HTML also.

1. Remove the ng-app from your HTML
2. Change the bootstrap code to:

`angular.bootstrap($('#outerDiv'), ['myApp']);`

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

But still, if the ajax page takes a few seconds to load you'll still see the curly braces. To fix this you can use i.e. ng-bind instead.

```
<p>The number in stock is: <span ng-bind="numInStock"></span></p>
```

Plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/c6Y0kQulzvLbI2iCp7HZ?p=preview

Comment: I don't want to remove ng-app in show.ejs, because only show.ejs is bind to angular app, and homepage.ejs should stay away from angular. And I tried angular.bootstrap($('#outerDiv'), ['myApp']), not working...

Comment: When using bootstrap you don't need to use ng-app. You don't have to add it to any other page..

Comment: Thanks for your demo. I finally found the reason. It's because $('#outerDiv').load("food/show"), this page contains not only <script>and <div> but also layout.ejs, which is a feature of Sails I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is missing the `#`:

```
angular.bootstrap($("#outerDiv"));
```

You could also use `this` as it will reference the same element and save another request to the DOM.

```
angular.bootstrap($(this));
```

Comment: It's my mistype, my real program has #. And I tried $(this). It does not work either.